# How to filter a data frame from another data frame while also adding a column from the second data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, join, dplyr

I wanted to know the easiest way to do a simple function whose aim is to:

1. I want to filter the First data frame using ID* from a second data frame.
2. I also want to add a new column to the filtered data from the second column corresponding to the ID* it is linked to.

I've provided a sample code in which `maindata` is the primary data and Age* from `subdata` has to be added to the `maindata` while filtering only the IDs* present in the subdata to have a data frame with ID,Name and Age. This final data frame is named `finaldata`

**Sample code:**

```
library(dplyr)
maindata = data.frame(ID=c(1:10), Name=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"))
subdata = data.frame(ID=c(1,3,6,2,7), Age=c(26,34,33,55,21))
#This is what I would like to have
finaldata = data.frame(ID=c(1,3,6,2,7), Name=c("a","c","f","b","7"), Age=c(26,34,33,55,21))

# I've tried using dplyr with no luck, This must be very basic :(
finaldata = maindata %>%
              filter(ID %in% subdata$ID) %>%
              mutate(Age=subdata$Age)
```

*Header names from example

Comment: `subdata$Name <- maindata$Name[match(subdata$ID, maindata$ID)]`

Comment: `merge(maindata, subdata, by="ID", all.y=TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do `inner_join` between the two datasets based on `ID`

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(maindata, subdata)

Joining, by = "ID"
   ID Name Age
1  1    a  26
2  2    b  55
3  3    c  34
4  6    f  33
5  7    g  21
```